Why getting "remote fetches not permitted" in console while debugging React-native app?
While debugging a react-native app, and accessing edge://inspect/#devices page and then clicking on Inspect of option Hermes React Native I am getting this error:
Failed to fetch source map http://192.168.4.100:8081/index.map?platform=android&dev=true&lazy=true&minify=false&app=com.sqlite1&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true: remote fetches not permitted

Due to this error I can't able to set breakpoints and debug my react-native app. Any help is appreciated!

I am there are other workarounds to set breakpoints, but I really appreciate someone can highlight why this happened.
